# Bootstrap 4 - Alignment

Tags: bootstrap-4, alignment

I can't align the following content both horizontally and vertically.

Can someone tell me the best approach for this ?

```html
<div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="flip-card text-center top-to-bottom">
                                ...
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="flip-card text-center">
                                ...
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="flip-card text-center">
                                ...
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="flip-card text-center">
                                ...
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="flip-card text-center">
                                ...
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="flip-card text-center top-to-bottom">
                                ...
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

view of the site [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0SG0.png)

i want it to be like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TjjR.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="well">1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="well">2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="well">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="well">4
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="well">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="well">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You should only need 2 rows. Without the full HTML is hard to be exact but you should make your first two rows into one, with a [column break](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#column-breaks) so that the 2 pictures move to a new line. From there you just need to adjust your padding and margins.

Comment: Thank you for your help.